# Angular 6 template driven form add custom validation with condition

Tags: angular, validation

I am using `template driven form` in `angular 6`.

I added a `custom validation` named `identityNumberValidator` for identity number field that check if user typed correct identity number (IL identity)

The validation directive looks as bellow:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[identityNumberValidator]',
    providers: [
        {
            provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
            useExisting: IdentityNumberValidator,
            multi: true
        }
    ]
})
export class IdentityNumberValidator implements Validator {
    validator: ValidatorFn;

    constructor() {
        this.validator = this.identityNumberValidator();
    }

    validate(c: FormControl) {
        return this.validator(c);
    }


    identityNumberValidator(): ValidatorFn {
        return (c: FormControl) => {
            let isValid = true;
            if (c.value && c.value.length >= 9) {
                let idNum = c.value.padStart(9, '0');
                // CHECK THE ID NUMBER algoritm - http://halemo.net/info/idcard/
                let mone = 0;
                for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                    var incNum = idNum[i];
                    incNum *= (i % 2) + 1;
                    if (incNum > 9)
                        incNum -= 9;
                    mone += incNum;
                }
                if (mone % 10 !== 0) {
                    isValid = false;
                }
                else {
                    isValid = true;
                }
            }

            if (isValid == true) {
                return null;
            } else {
                return {
                    identityNumberValidator: {
                        valid: false
                    }
                };
            }
        }
    }
```

I Use it in my component for input element here:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
            <mat-label>מספר מזהה</mat-label>
            <input matInput
                   maxlength="9"
                   minlength="9"
                   required
                   identityNumberValidator
                   #identityNumberField="ngModel"
                   [(ngModel)]="identityNumber"
                   name="identityNumberField" />
            <mat-error *ngIf="identityNumberField.errors?.required">
              {{ eMessages.required}}
            </mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="identityNumberField.errors?.minlength">
              יש להזין 9 ספרות
            </mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="identityNumberField.errors?.identityNumberValidator">
              מספר זהות שגוי
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
```

My question is how can I use this validation with condition on other element?

I tried `[identityNumberValidator] = "element == 1 ? '' : null"`
but does not work. I read this post 
[Angular conditional validation on template driven form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48777059/angular-conditional-validation-on-template-driven-form)

but both [attr.identityNumberValidator] and [class.identityNumberValidator] does not work. The validation does not appear at all.

I know I can use reactive form but I do not want to.

So I can use two different input elements and use *ngIf between them but I want to find a solution to use **only one element**.

Any Idea?

Comment: Could you add your validator code please?

Comment: read some examples [here](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/11/10/angular-7-template-driven-forms-validation-example)

Comment: `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself` : please provide a [mcve]. As for your issue, please provide at least some code, to know if you followed the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#adding-to-template-driven-forms) (and if not, then follow it)

Comment: Another example using a directive to validate a template driven form https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56716216/angular-custom-validator-on-multiple-fields/56724287?noredirect=1#comment100023869_56724287. It's only make a directive that implements Validator, that has a provider `providers: [{ provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: RepeatNameDirective, multi: true }]` and use a `@Input`to get the argument

Comment: Hi, I added sample code

Answer (score 0):

You can bind you custom function in the template driven approach, but that can be possible through @rxweb/reactive-form-validators.

Here, I have used `[compose]` attribute on input filed where I have passed the validator method and set conditional expression. See the code below:

```
[compose]="{validators:[identityNumberValidator.bind(this)],'conditionalExpression':'x => x.userName == \'Bharat\''}"
```

Here is the complete HTML. where I have defined two control, 'userName' and 'firstName' the firstname validation will be fired once the 'userName' control value is 'Bharat'.
See the below HTML code snippet.

```html
    <div>
      <form #userinfoForm = "ngForm" [rxwebForm]="userinfoForm" [model]="userinfo">
         <div class="form-group">
          <label>User Name</label>
         <input type="text" name="userName" [(ngModel)]="userinfo.userName"  class="form-control" />
    
       
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>First Name</label>
         <input type="text" name="firstName" [(ngModel)]="userinfo.firstName"  class="form-control" [compose]="{validators:[identityNumberValidator.bind(this)],'conditionalExpression':'x => x.userName == \'Bharat\''}"/>
    
     
        </div>
        <button [disabled]="!userinfoForm.valid" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Here is the control custom method:

```js
   identityNumberValidator =  (c: FormControl) => {
       
          let a = this;
          return {"msg":""};
        }
```

**[Stackbliz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3htt38-u3yak4?file=src/app/required-add.component.ts)**